# How do I copy files from Windows partition to my Ubuntu partition

Tags: command-line, windows, clipboard

I am dual-booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu and I have many important files on my Windows OS. I've been trying to copy the files from windows to my Ubuntu home directory but the paste option is disabled when I rt click in my home dir.

How can I copy the files? What is the command to copy files from my D drive if using console with sudo?

Comment: install ntfs-3g, for read/write permission on an NTFS drive `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`

Comment: @blade19899 `ntfs-3g` is installed by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: Just paste it with selecting the "disabled paste option" or ctrl-v

Comment: Just try use the linux's native shell Nautilus. It can read ntfs partitions natively, and simply using ctrl+c & ctrl+v you shall can do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te console command is: `sudo cp -R /mounted/win/hdd/location/ /target/location/`

Comment: `sudo` is not needed

Comment: Umar asked for command with sudo. ;)